# How to make the service work even when the application is unloaded from the task list

Tags: android, kotlin

I wrote a program that generates a random number every 3 seconds and displays it using Toast. The program works even when another application is open or the phone is unlocked. But if you remove it from the list of tasks, then the program will end, although I did it using Service. Tell me how you can make the program work even when it is unloaded from the task list

```
package com.example.reminder

import android.app.ActivityManager
import android.app.Notification
import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory
import android.graphics.Color
import android.os.Build
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    //declaring variables
    lateinit var notificationManager : NotificationManager
    lateinit var notificationChannel : NotificationChannel
    lateinit var builder : Notification.Builder
    private val channelId = "reminder1"
    private val identifierChannelId = 1234
    private val description = "Test notification"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val btnStart = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnEnter)
        val btnStop = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnStop)

        val serviceClass = NotificationService::class.java
        val intent = Intent(this, serviceClass)

        btnStart.setOnClickListener {
            if(!isServiceRunning(serviceClass)) {
                startService(intent)
            } else {
                toast("Service already running!")
                Log.e("TARGET: ", "Service already running!")
            }
        }

        btnStop.setOnClickListener {
            if(isServiceRunning(serviceClass)) {
                stopService(intent)
            } else {
                toast("Service already stopped!")
                Log.e("TARGET: ", "Service already stopped!")
            }
        }
    }

    // Custom method to determine whether a service is running
    private fun isServiceRunning(serviceClass: Class<*>): Boolean {
        val activityManager = getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager

        // Loop through the running services
        for (service in activityManager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (serviceClass.name == service.service.className) {
                // If the service is running then return true
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }

}

// Extension function to show toast message
fun Context.toast(message: String) {
    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

//SERVICE CODE
package com.example.reminder

```
import android.app.Notification
import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.app.Service
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory
import android.graphics.Color
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.IBinder
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import java.util.*
import com.example.reminder.MainActivity as MainActivity

class NotificationService: Service() {
    private lateinit var mHandler: Handler
    private lateinit var mRunnable: Runnable

    lateinit var notificationManager : NotificationManager
    lateinit var notificationChannel : NotificationChannel
    lateinit var builder : Notification.Builder

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        throw UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented")
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        toast("Started")
        Log.e("TARGET: ", "Started")
        // Do a periodic task
        mHandler = Handler()

        notificationManager =
            getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        mRunnable = Runnable {
            showRandomNumber()
        }
        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 3000)

        return START_STICKY
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        toast("Service destroyed.")
        Log.e("TARGET: ", "Service destroyed.")
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable)
    }

    // Custom method to do a task
    private fun showRandomNumber() {
        val rand = Random()
        val number = rand.nextInt(100)
        toast("Random Number: " + number)
        Log.e("TARGET: ", "Random Number: " + number)
        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 3000)
    }
}
```

//MANIFEST

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.reminder"
    >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service
            android:exported="false"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:name=".NotificationService"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Use Foreground Service [Documentation] https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#:~:text=A%20foreground%20service%20performs%20some,t%20interacting%20with%20the%20app.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **Foreground Service** and be sure to include **android:stopWithTask** for your service.

[I wrote an article about this.](https://dev.to/localazy/2-floating-windows-on-android-foreground-service-3m64)